# Hide characters in Tktable

Tags: tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a TK gui, where I put some parameters along with password. I want that password to be hidden from user. So I used entry widget with `-show *` option.

For some reasons I have to change widget to tablelist instead of entry (I am also looking Tktable option).
Do we have some measure to hide characters in tablelist or tk table?

Comment: are we talking __ttk::entry__ or __tkinter::entry__? Makes all the difference in the world.

Comment: @NationWidePants This is in ttk::entry where we use -show * for hiding out our text.

Comment: Tkinter is _just_ a wrapper round Tk to embed it into Python.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether your program is in tcl/tk or tkinter.  `tablelist` and `Tktable` do not exist in tkinter, so you must either be writing tcl/tk or using an undiclosed 3rd party Python module with tkinter.  The general approach to replacing chars with *s is to bind <Any-Keypress> to a function that makes the replacement and return 'break' to disable normal display.

Comment: Code is in Tcl/Tk.
Just now got it worked somehow. We can get the current editing cell entry  by appending .f.e in the path name of tablelist, where i can use show

.restGUI.baseFrame.paramFrame.bodyBaseFrame.bodyTableList.body.f.e configure -show *

Thanks all for commenting

Answer (score 2):

Code is in Tcl/Tk. Just now got it worked somehow. We can get the current editing cell entry by appending .f.e in the path name of tablelist, where i can use show `.restGUI.baseFrame.paramFrame.bodyBaseFrame.bodyTableList.body.f.e configure -show *`

we can get entry path by `pathName entrypath`
But when I am coming out of editing mode, it displays clear text, not hidden.
Need to figure out other way.